# How can I make a div disappear and reappear on button click?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code so far :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#panel').hide();

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#panel").fadeIn(3000);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<center><button class="button" id="button">CLUJ</button></center>

    <div class="panel" id='panel'>
        <p>
            Universitatea Alexandru Ioan Cuza din Iasi <br><br>
            Universitatea din Craiova <br><br>
            Universitatea din Bucuresti <br><br>
            Universitatea Babes-Bolyai din Cluj-Napoca <br><br>
        </p>
    </div>
```

1.The div doesn't hide;
2.How can I make the div appear and disappear on button click? (Something like an accordion)

Comment: fadeIn() fadeOut can help you with solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `fadeToggle` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#panel").fadeToggle(3000);
    });
});
```

And to initially hide the div, just add this to your css:

```
#panel    {
    display:none;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bgepfuhb/3/

---

For more than one panel, you can add unique IDs like this:

```
    <center><button class="button" id="buttonA">CLUJ</button></center>
    <div class="panel" id='panelA'>
        <p>....</p>
    </div>

    <center><button class="button" id="buttonB">CLUJ</button></center>

    <div class="panel" id='panelB'>
        <p>....</p>
    </div>

    <center><button class="button" id="buttonC">CLUJ</button></center>

    <div class="panel" id='panelC'>
        <p>....</p>
    </div>
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bgepfuhb/7/

Comment: How can I make the div invisible when I first open the page?

Comment: I dopn't understand. You mean more buttons and divs?

Comment: Exactly what I meant

Comment: All the panels will be hidden and shown with the same button or their own respective buttons?

Comment: Each div has its own button

Comment: Oh that's easy. Hold on. I'll create a new fiddle

Comment: Thank you so much ! But why for every button do I have to write the document ready function again?

Comment: @VladJ No you don't. Sorry about that. Second fiddle updated with single document ready.

Comment: Can you try clearing cache and checking the above fiddle again.

Comment: I cleared cache and it works just fine ! Thanks again. Any idea why can't I see that FADE animation?

Comment: Can it be the Adobe Flash Player?

Comment: I mean I get the 3000 delay but I can't see the animation

Comment: Can you provide an example link of another site having the fade effect you're talking about.

Comment: I'm a tad bit confused honestly.

Comment: The effect in your fiddle. I can see it in the fiddle but I can't see it on my webpage.

Comment: Can you give me a link to your website.

Comment: It's still a html file stored on my PC :(

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to help you debug the issue without actually seeing the site Vlad.

Answer (score 1):

Hide and fade is not the same.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#panel').fadeOut(1); // <-- try 0
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#panel").fadeIn(3000);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeToggle();
        $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
        $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);
    });
});
</script>


<p>Demonstrate fadeToggle() with different speed parameters.</p>

<button>Click to fade in/out boxes</button><br><br>

<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div>

<br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Hope it helps;)

Answer (score 0):

use the fadeToggle(); function (or any of the several other JQuery Toggle functions available)

JQ, CSS, and HTML below

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('.togglebutton').toggle(function() {
    $('.hideshow').fadeToggle(300);
  }, function() {
    $('.hideshow').fadeToggle(300);
  });
   
   });
```

```css
.hideshow
{
  display:none;
  }

.togglebutton
{ 
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=togglebutton>
  <p> click me to toggle the next one </p>
  </div>

<div class=hideshow>
  <p> BOO! </p>
  </div>
```